# new directory but the default doesn't receive calls

Tags: directory, freeswitch

The default directories come with freeswitch working fine but when I add a new directory like 2000.xml file it does not receive calls but it can dial the directories come with freeswitch
it gave

> sofia.c:10044 IP x.x.x.x Rejected by acl "domains". Falling back to
>   Digest auth.

Answer (score 0):

Acls are to block domain only but if you receive calls on default then Check your dialplan configuration for 2xxx.